# Movie about drug with hybrid animation and live action

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a movie with a female lead (maybe) that begins with her and her children living in an airport. She then goes to a convention inside an "animated zone" (live action up till this point) which I think was induced by some drug. Something goes wrong, then the whole world becomes animated; time passes and then she eventually breaks out of the animation and goes to a blimp. I don't remember much else but I think she may return to the animated zone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*The Congress* (2013).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Congress_(2013_film)):

> Robin Wright plays a fictionalized version of herself as an aging actress with a reputation for being fickle and unreliable, so much so that nobody is willing to offer her roles. [...]
>
> Robin's longtime agent Al (Harvey Keitel) takes her to met Jeff Green (Danny Huston), a CEO of the film production company, **Miramount Studios, who offers to buy her likeness and digitize her into a computer-animated version of herself.** [...] After her body is digitally scanned, the studio will be able to make films starring her, using only computer-generated characters. Since then, Robin's virtual persona has become the star of a popular science-fiction action film franchise, "Rebel Robot Robin".
>
> Twenty years later, as her contract is about to expire, Robin travels to Abrahama City where she will speak at Miramount's entertainment conference called the "Futurological Congress" in Hotel Miramount Nagasaki, and also renew her expiring contract. **Abrahama City is an animated, surreal utopia that is created from figments of people's imaginations, where anyone can become an animated avatar of themselves, but are required to use hallucinogenic drugs that allow them to enter a mutable illusory state.** They can become anything they want to be. Avatars as varied as Michael Jackson and Frida Kahlo and falcon-headed Egyptian god Horus are seen at the Congress. [...]
>
> **Re-entering the un-animated real world, Robin finds herself in a dystopian environment and the inhabitants are severely dysfunctional.** Those who are still able to cope in the real world hover over its ruined cities in large airships. On one of the ships, Robin finds Doctor Barker, who reveals the state of the real world in which most people have left for an existence in an animated, unreal world. Wanting to find Aaron, Robin's hopes are dashed when Barker reveals that Aaron "crossed over" into the animated world only six months earlier, when his condition had left him virtually blind and deaf. Because Aaron likely created a new identity for himself in the animated world, there is no way for anyone to find him. While Robin can return to an animated existence, she cannot return to the one she left behind, including Dylan, because that world was not real but created by her consciousness.
>
> **Dr. Barker gives Robin an inhalation ampule that will allow her to return to the animated world once again.** Taking it, Robin experiences a vivid vision based on memories of her son's life... [...]

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie live action animation drug airport site:imdb.com/title`.